# WPF collection dependency property adding duplicates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I've created a class that declares an attached property which will hold a collection of datatemplates:

```
public class DynamicTemplatesList : DependencyObject
 {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplatesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Templates", typeof(TemplateCollection), typeof(DynamicTemplatesList), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new TemplateCollection(), 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

    public static void SetTemplates(UIElement element, TemplateCollection collection)
        {
            element.SetValue(TemplatesProperty, collection);
        }
}
```

And then in xaml I set the collection:

```
        <gfc:DynamicTemplatesList.Templates>
            <gfc:Template Key="{StaticResource CheckBoxFieldType}"
                                         DataTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}" />
            <gfc:Template Key="{StaticResource LookupEditFieldType}"
                                         DataTemplate="{StaticResource LookupEditTemplate}" />
            <gfc:Template Key="{StaticResource TextBoxFieldType}"
                                         DataTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
            <gfc:Template Key="{StaticResource DateEditFieldType}"
                                         DataTemplate="{StaticResource DateEditTemplate}" />
        </gfc:DynamicTemplatesList.Templates>
```

This seems to work fine the first time.  However one thing I've noticed is that when I close the window with this dependency property and then re-open it again,
it seems the templates are added again to the collection.

First time, there would be 4 templates in the collection, 2nd time 8, so on and so forth.  Can anyone explain to me what is occurring here?

I suspect it is because the static nature of dependency properties why values are being duplicated and if that is the case can anyone point me to a solution to prevent the attached collection property from adding duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set `new TemplateCollection()` as the default value of the dependency property. This "static" collection instance will be used whenever you use your property without assigning it before, as you do in your XAML.

You should never use anything else than `null` for the default value of a dependency property that holds a modifiable collection.

```
public class DynamicTemplatesList
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Templates",
            typeof(TemplateCollection),
            typeof(DynamicTemplatesList));

     public static TemplateCollection GetTemplates(UIElement element)
     {
         return (TemplateCollection)element.GetValue(TemplatesProperty);
     }

     public static void SetTemplates(UIElement element, TemplateCollection collection)
     {
         element.SetValue(TemplatesProperty, collection);
     }
}
```

Now explicitly assign a `TemplateCollection` instance in XAML like this:

```
<gfc:DynamicTemplatesList.Templates>
    <gfc:TemplateCollection>
        <gfc:Template ... />
        <gfc:Template ... />
        <gfc:Template ... />
        <gfc:Template ... />
    </gfc:TemplateCollection>
</gfc:DynamicTemplatesList.Templates>
```

---

As a note, your class does not need to derive from `DependencyObject` if it only registers attached properties.

Comment: It seems that if I change the default value of the dependency property from new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new TemplateCollection(), 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None) to null when I load the related xaml control it throws a null exception stating that Templates property is null.

Comment: One other thing is that don't I need to derive from DependencyObject to have access to SetCurrentValue method?

Comment: Yes, I did make the change to the constructor

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the answer. You have to assign a new instance of the TemplateCollection to the property before you can use it.

Comment: Yup I explictled assigned in the same way in the XAML.  The problem I'm having now is that I can't seem to retrieve these templates in my DataTemplateSelector:

Comment: I was using var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container);
            var templates = (TemplateCollection)parent
                .GetValue(DynamicTemplatesList.TemplatesProperty);  In my datatemplate selector and it was working before but doesn't work with the new way the attached property is declared and instantiated.

Comment: You have to get the `Templates` property value from exactly the object that you've set it on before. It worked before due to the "static" effect of the default value. You always got the same collection object, regardless of where you called GetValue.

Comment: Yea you're right.  Seems now I have to find the exact object I set that templates property

Comment: Well, you're doing it in XAML. Set `x:Name` on that object and access it in code behind by the generated field.

Comment: Actually used this method to go up visual tree:private TemplateCollection FindTemplates(DependencyObject container)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (container == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var templates = (TemplateCollection) container.GetValue(DynamicTemplatesList.TemplatesProperty);

                if (templates != null) return templates;
                container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container);
            }
        }